# Couldn't trigger high priority email using Sendgrid SMPT to outlook in java

Tags: java, email, smtp, sendgrid

Couldnt able to trigger high priority email using Sendgrid SMPT to outlook in java
 I have added below headers

```
"X-Priority", "1"
"Priority", "urgent"
"Importance", "high"
```

Still i'm receiving email as LOW PRIORITY, even after changing from 1 to 5 still the same as LOW PRIORITY.

Email configuration :

```
public static final String HIGH_PRIORITY_EMAIL ="X-Priority";
public static final String PRIORITY_LEVEL ="1"; 
public static final String IMPORTANT_EMAIL ="Importance"; 
public static final String IMPORTANT_LEVEL ="high"; 
public static final String HIGH_PRIORITY_EMAIL_PROPERTY ="Priority";
public static final String HIGH_PRIORITY_LEVEL="urgent"`

HtmlEmail erroremail; 
erroremail = (HtmlEmail) MailUtils.getPreConfiguredEmail(); erroremail.addHeader(Constants.HIGH_PRIORITY_EMAIL,Constants.PRIORITY_LEVE); erroremail.addHeader(Constants.HIGH_PRIORITY_EMAIL_PROPERTY,Constants.HIGH_PRIORITY_LEVEL);
erroremail.addHeader(Constants.IMPORTANT_EMAIL, Constants.IMPORTANT_LEVEL); 
erroremail.send();
```

Though I'm setting headers as high priority, receiving emails as low priority.

Comment: Can you show code you're using to do this?

Comment: `HtmlEmail erroremail;
erroremail = (HtmlEmail) MailUtils.getPreConfiguredEmail();
erroremail.addHeader(Constants.HIGH_PRIORITY_EMAIL,Constants.PRIORITY_LEVEL);
erroremail.addHeader(Constants.HIGH_PRIORITY_EMAIL_PROPERTY,Constants.HIGH_PRIORITY_LEVEL);erroremail.addHeader(Constants.IMPORTANT_EMAIL, Constants.IMPORTANT_LEVEL);
  erroremail.send();`

Comment: Constants:                                                                                                        
  `public static final String HIGH_PRIORITY_EMAIL ="X-Priority";
 public static final String PRIORITY_LEVEL ="1";
 public static final String IMPORTANT_EMAIL ="Importance";
 public static final String IMPORTANT_LEVEL ="high";
 public static final String HIGH_PRIORITY_EMAIL_PROPERTY ="Priority";
 public static final String HIGH_PRIORITY_LEVEL="urgent"`

Comment: Please put your code in your question, not in comments. This will allow you to indent it properly so we can understand it :)

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Updated.Thanks